# Transferring data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, loops

The below script currently loops through a list of data and copies a range from one workbook to another depending on a value in a cell.

```
For i = 3 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 13) = "ü" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 12)).Select
Selection.Copy

workbooks.Open Filename:=iForm
Worksheets("Statistics").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Worksheets("Statistics").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next i
```

Rather copying the range from A:L I would like to copy columns A & L, I've tried updating this however I keep getting errors, please help.
I thank you in advance.

Comment: When using multiple workbooks/worksheets, you should use variables to store those.  [Don't use `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). You're probably getting errors from that.  For instance, `erow` should equal `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`, but you should swich out the `Activesheet` with the one you intend to work with.  Also, what errors do you get, at what line?

Comment: @BruceWayne. In an attempt to copy A & L i adjusted the following line which returns an error 13 (type mismatch) `Range(Cells(i, 1) And Cells(i, 12)).Select`

Comment: That's odd - it shouldn't. What is the code before that? I'm going to assume it's your use of the worksheets. If the data is on the "Statistics" sheet, try this: `Worksheets("Statistics").Range(Worksheets("Statistics").Cells(i, 1), Worksheets("Statistics").Cells(i, 12)).Select`

Comment: Isn't the solution provided copying the range from A to L rather than A and L? Coping the entire row is not an issue, i'm just trying to copy those two columns in particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying. I suggest giving your worksheets a variable, and then you can select entire columns via `Range()`:

```
Sub t()
Dim mainWS As Worksheet
Set mainWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Tweak as necessary, this sheet is where your main data is (the non-blank cell, and "ü") 

lastRow = mainWS.Cells(mainWS.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'or whatever your formula is. Make sure to reference the worksheet

For i = 3 To lastRow
    If mainWS.Cells(i, 1) <> "" And mainWS.Cells(i, 13) = "ü" Then
        mainWS.Range("A:A,L:L").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=iForm
        'Worksheets("Statistics").Select
        Set statWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Statistics")

        erow = statWS.Cells(statWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        statWS.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

And note, I left in `.Select`, just to keep it similar to your OP. Although you should definitely look into [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: This is great, thanks Bruce. Admittedly it's not quite working yet but I can tweak it to work with my sheet. Thank you :)